# Tablayout vertical tab layout with badge

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been having some problems with this particular layout for the better part of an hour, and I can't seem to get it to layout as expected. I've done the usual googling around this sort of format for the tab, and nothing seems to be exactly what I'm after.

I have a TabLayout where the tabs are laid out vertically, with an ImageView and a TextView using the default View of the tab.

It looks like this:

[image: Home tab]

Ideally all I want to be able to do is to mimic this layout and anchor a TextView as a badge counter to the top right of the icon.

Like this:

[image: Home tab with badge example]

So with that in mind I found a decent approximation of how the default tab layouts actually appear and it used the default ID's so I don't have to assign them programmatically which I thought was pretty nifty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_selector"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/badgeCounter"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:minWidth="20dp"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:background="@drawable/count_background"
      android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After a lot of tinkering and trying different things, I got to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/iconFrame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/text1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_home" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_selector"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Home"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badgeCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:minWidth="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconFrame"
        android:textColor="@color/FeatureFontColour"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/count_background"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iconFrame" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

No matter what I try, I can't get the badge TextView to appear in the right place, I've tried removing the linear layout so that I can set it to Layout_RightOf the @android:id/icon, I've tried wrapping the icon in a frame and setting Layout_RightOf that instead just incase the icon was not positioned before the badge TextView was created etc.

This is as close as I can get (Spoiler, not that close):

[image: Tab]

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing, but odds are it's something really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
  android:clipChildren="false"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/iconFrame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_above="@android:id/text1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_home" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badgeCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:minWidth="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/FeatureFontColour"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/count_background"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
   </FrameLayout>
   <TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/tab_selector"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Home"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

You can play with the margin right/top values to fine tune it.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer. This is actually really close, only downside is that the frame layout appears to cut off parts of the badgeCounter TextView.

Comment: So add a `android:clipChildren="false"` on the FrameLayout

Comment: Yeah tried that, interestingly still does the same thing, might try a clean, rebuild make sure it's not Xamarin doing something bizzare as usual. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I never checked how it looks, you can add padding to the FrameLayout and add `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Comment: Turns out after a little more googling you're spot on, but I also had to add android:clipChildren="false" to all parent views, including the grandparent which in this case was the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Just built it out to simulator with a few margin adjustments and this has laid it out perfectly, thank you kindly. You've likely saved me a fair amount of time today. I'm going to mark your answer as accepted, might be worth just adding that cliptopadding on the relative view for completeness. Cheers bud.

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167177/discussion-between-hed-shafran-and-digitalsa1nt).

Answer (score 1):

Creating a layer drawable to display menu item on layer one and badge on top of it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cart"
    android:gravity="center" />
      <item
    android:id="@+id/ic_badge"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cart" />
</layer-list>
```

Creating menu for our activity to display the count on the menu items.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.mobikul.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_cart"
    android:title="@string/action_cart"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Creating a flexible and efficient custom BagdeDrawable class to draw a view that looks like a count

```
public class BadgeDrawable extends Drawable {

private Paint mBadgePaint;
private Paint mBadgePaint1;
private Paint mTextPaint;
private Rect mTxtRect = new Rect();

private String mCount = "";
private boolean mWillDraw;

public BadgeDrawable(Context context) {
    float mTextSize = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.badge_text_size);

    mBadgePaint = new Paint();
    mBadgePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mBadgePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBadgePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mBadgePaint1 = new Paint();
    mBadgePaint1.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(), R.color.grey_ivory5));
    mBadgePaint1.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBadgePaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {



    if (!mWillDraw) {
        return;
    }
    Rect bounds = getBounds();
    float width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    float height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

    // Position the badge in the top-right quadrant of the icon.

        /*Using Math.max rather than Math.min */

    float radius = ((Math.max(width, height) / 2)) / 2;
    float centerX = (width - radius - 1) +5;
    float centerY = radius -5;
    if(mCount.length() <= 2){
        // Draw badge circle.
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, (int)(radius+7.5), mBadgePaint1);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, (int)(radius+5.5), mBadgePaint);
    }
    else{
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, (int)(radius+8.5), mBadgePaint1);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, (int)(radius+6.5), mBadgePaint);
    }
    mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mCount, 0, mCount.length(), mTxtRect);
    float textHeight = mTxtRect.bottom - mTxtRect.top;
    float textY = centerY + (textHeight / 2f);
    if(mCount.length() > 2)
        canvas.drawText("99+", centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
    else
        canvas.drawText(mCount, centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
}

/*
Sets the count (i.e notifications) to display.
 */
public void setCount(String count) {
    mCount = count;

    // Only draw a badge if there are notifications.
    mWillDraw = !count.equalsIgnoreCase("0");
    invalidateSelf();
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN;
}
}
```

for more referance visit this website[visit here](https://mobikul.com/adding-badge-count-on-menu-items-like-cart-notification-etc/)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you missed here is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/lnrButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="4dp">
    <ImageView
       android:id="@android:id/icon"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_width="24dp"
       android:layout_height="24dp"
       android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    <TextView
       android:id="@android:id/text1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@drawable/tab_selector"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:textAllCaps="true"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:maxLines="2" />
 </LinearLayout>
 <TextView
       android:id="@+id/badgeCounter"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:alignRight = "@+id/lnrButton"
       android:alignTop = "@+id/lnrButton"
       android:minWidth="20dp"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:background="@drawable/count_background"
       android:textSize="15sp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Following is you missed

```
       android:alignRight = "@+id/lnrButton"
       android:alignTop = "@+id/lnrButton"
```

or if you want to come the badge on the image means, remove all LinearLayout and make it Relativelaout and instead of `lnrButton` use imageview id

Comment: I did actually try this, but something about the way the tablayout sizes it's tab's child views forces the tabs layout to extend right far further than you'd expect. Quite odd behaviour, but replicable.

Comment: what tablayout you are using?

Comment: If I remember correctly it's part of the Xamarin.Android.Support.Design nuget package. https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents

Comment: this will work default tablayout.android.support.design.widget.TabLayout